# How do I identify the "Azure subscription email"?

Tags: azure

I am trying to apply Startup Hub Azure credits. The [instructions](https://foundershubsupportcenter.powerappsportals.com/category/?id=CAT-01004) say:

> After logging into the Microsoft for Startups Founders Hub, go to the
> Benefits tab and select Redeem in the Azure sponsorship benefits
> section. Use your Azure subscription email when redeeming credits.

However, I don't actually know what my "Azure subscription email" is. How do I find out what this email is? I assume it has to be an identifier specific to this subscription, since the credits need to be applied to a particular subscription (I think.)

Comment: Do you have an `@your-tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com` address set-up?

Answer (score 0):

If you've missed your Founders Hub email.
Please login to https://www.microsoftazuresponsorships.com/
Azure Sponsorships & check your balance.
Your Azure sponsorship subscription must be listed there.
If you still face any issue, please open a support request ticket within Billing & Subscriptions over Azure portal.